# Cpanel mass DB import from root user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have been tasked with migrating a VPS previously build on a very shady centos 5 system (no hosting environment) into a perfectly working centos 7/cpanel environment. The old server setup had 29 websites using the root MySQL user/password in order to get his connections to work. I imported the databases and matched the root password but this is really not an ideal setup because the databases are not linked to the cpanel user and well using the root password in production is very bad...

So my question is, now that the databases are on the server (can only be seen from the root phpmyadmin) how can I link them to a cpanel account?

From the root PHPMyAdmin in WHM, there was no "user" tab which is odd. I guess cpanel made sure all the databases were created from its cpanel system. But how can I link all the databases if I can't access that page? If the only way is by SSH, is there a way to do them all in batch?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to do this as far as I know.

The best option (unfortunatelly it involves some work and non automated actions) is to login to each of the accounts cPanel account (you can do that from WHM by clicking on the cPanel account which is displayed next to the cPanel account when you use List Accounts) and then use the SQL section to create a new database, a new user for that database, provided grants to that user.

Then you can use the Database Map Tool available in WHM to grant access to that database to a specific cPanel user, map rights and so on. You have to repeat this for each of your cPanel accounts. Last but not least, you'll have to modify the configuration files for each of your websites to reflect the new mysql settings (db name, user, password etc).

I know this is a slow and step by step method but it would be the best and safest especially that 29 accounts are not that much.